# Python: How To Get The Number Of Items In One List Which Belong To Another

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a list of ~3000 items. Let's call it `listA`. 
And another list with 1,000,000 items. Let's call it `listB`.

I want to check how many items of `listA` belong in `listB`. For example to get an answer like `436`.

The obvious way is to have a nested loop looking for each item, but this is slow, especially due to the size of the lists.

What is the fastest and/or Pythonic way to get the number of the items of one list belonging to another?

Comment: Do the lists have duplicate values? Does order (e.g. the item index) matter?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make a set out of `list_b`. That will avoid nested loops and make the contains-check `O(1)`. The entire process will be `O(M+N)` which should be fairly optimal:

```
set_b = set(list_b)
count = sum(1 for a in list_a if a in set_b)
# OR shorter, but maybe less intuitive
count = sum(a in set_b for a in list_a)  
# where the bool expression is coerced to int {0; 1} for the summing
```

If you don't want to (or have to) count repeated elements in `list_a`, you can use set intersection:

```
count = len(set(list_a) & set(list_b))
# OR
count = len(set(list_a).intersection(list_b))  # avoids one conversion
```

One should also note that these set-based operations only work if the items in your lists are hashable (e.g. not lists themselves)!

Comment: You can simplify the second version by skipping the conversion of `list_b` and using the method form: `set(list_a).intersection(list_b)`.

Comment: Thank you, that worked like a charm and it was really fast :)

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use `set` and find the intersection:

```
len(set(listA).intersection(listB))
```

Comment: Most algorithmic performance wise. In this case, `listA` happens to be the smallest, but in general the smallest iterable should be called in `set()` for quick lookup while the traversal is the longer iterable.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over the contents of `listA` and use a generator to yield values to be more efficient:

```
def get_number_of_elements(s, a):
    for i in s:
       if i in a:
          yield i
print(len(list(get_number_of_elements(listA, listB))))
```

Comment: This does not solve the main performance issue of the nested loops if `a` is a list. `i in a` must still iterate through the list!
Besides, the generator function is quite misnamed because it does not return the number of elements.

Comment: @schwobaseggl the generator function will yield all elements in `s` that occur in `a`. The number of times repeats are found is calculated by passing the casted generator function to the `len` function.

Comment: I understand what it is doing ;) but a) it is specifically not solving the nested loopd issue the OP wanted to be solved and b) `get_number_of_elements(...)` is not getting the number of elements, but a generator over said elements.

Comment: This is a poor solution, and the generator doesn't help.

Comment: @Mitch I am not sure what you mean by "poor". Could you elaborate?

Comment: @Ajax1234 Sure. It is very inefficient, and somewhat bloated as the generator isn't of any use for counting the number of items. It is poor insofar as there are far better ways to solve the problem.

Comment: @Mitch a better method would be to solve the problem using a comprehension like the answers above; however, since those options were taken, I thought I would present a possible solution from a new angle.

Comment: @Ajax1234 Sure. I just felt it was worth noting that this is a poor approach for any future readers. Typically one answers when they have a good answer, not when they have _an_ answer.